# XmlDocument - I want <Item></Item> and not <Item/>

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, sap-basis

I have to send an XML as a SOAP response to a SAP WAS.

SAP is quite fussy with what you are sending (special characters and stuff), and by now I want to exhaust all possibilities.

Is there a way when you make a `myXMLDoc.LoadXml`
to specify something like *"do not shorten tags when empty"*?

Usually when you make this:

```
<item>
<Trkorr>TDEK978887</Trkorr>
<Sequence>0</Sequence>
<Solicit>cggaste</Solicit>
<Type></Type><Id></Id><Number></Number><Message></Message>
</item>
```

It transforms it to:

```
<item>
<Trkorr>TDEK978887</Trkorr>
<Sequence>0</Sequence>
<Solicit>cggaste</Solicit>
<Type/><Id/><Number/><Message/>
</item>
```

Any property I'm missing?

---

BTW *(I don't think it's worth another question, so...)*

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">SOAP processing failure, error id = 112</faultstring>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is the error sap's returning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to change LoadXml or SaveXml ?

Comment: @Henk I'm passing a string (builder) as parameter to the LoadXml method with a SOAP XML that is actually working when it's called from an ancient vbscript. But when I transcribe it to .Net, it fails miserably.

Comment: Still unclear how the data is passed along and with what libraries.

Comment: using System.Xml; and the old System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Comment: You're encountering a deserialization issue. Are you sure that your parameters are correct? I don't think the removal of endtags is your issue. If you have any documentation available (not an SAP user myself) verify that you have included all of the necessary parameters and that your tag spelling/capitalization is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't another way without writing everything yourself.

And even with that done, that's not the problem.
The problem is something on the SAP Server and/or the SAP Parameters you were sending beside those you show.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the end tags are the real problem. Take a look at [SAP note 1318784](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1318784) on how to enable tracing and use this to find out what's behind the error message 112.